# Wordpress json api not showing data from phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress

i am working on a WordPress site , back at c Panel i have "phpmyadmin" server where the user table exist .

i added custom columns in "phpmyadmin" user table .

now when i am requesting **json api** the fields i created in database doesn't appear in **api** .

i want know what i am doing wrong here how can i retrieve the added columns data in **json api** .

kindly provide any guide i am new to WordPress .

**here are the screenshots what i have done
wordpress phpmyadmin database:**
[image]

now here sender_wallet i have created column sender_wallet and entered the data 'Text'

[image]

**From here i have accessed the json api of the user data**

**now the json i get**

[image]

**it doesnot have sender_wallet or the data field .**

how can i bring that database value to my api . and i have to add other column aswel and fetch their data aswel in api .

kindly guide me how to achieve this .

Comment: is this json api a plugin ?

Comment: yes it is the json api plugin

Comment: I don't think you can do that by just adding fields in the database, because wordpress by itself is not aware of the new column. You might want to add a meta field. I don't know how to expose it in the api but it should be possible.

Comment: i tried in adding user-meta table also but then also didn't get sender_wallet field in json response,

Comment: is there any work around which makes it possible that i get database field in json api

Comment: don't fiddle with the database, read up wordpress documentation on how to add user meta fields.

Comment: @ggg is right this would be problem else if you database cache enabled then clear it and try again